# How to add a default spacing after a table in Word?

Tags: microsoft-word

I looked around in Table Styles, but the `Positionning` is not available by default. How can I specify the number of pixels I want after each table?

Comment: please post some screenshots too, it's not clear now what you want to achieve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The table would have to have wrapping text, which there is not an option to make the default. The other problem as you point out is the Positioning setting, which does not have a default setting that can be altered for all new tables.

What you will have to do is make a table, with all your custom settings including wrapping text and how many points to add to the bottom position. Then save your "template" of the table to AutoText and pop it in when needed.

There is one other option and that is an add-in called AuthorTec Tables. In essence, it lets you create new Table Styles that get saved into Word's Table Styles. I'm the author and if you want more information on it, just do a web search on the name, AuthorTec Tables.